# Adding to an HTML list using JQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some javascript which I want to be executed and change a list element when a button is clicked:

```
<button id="click-me" type="button">
     <img  src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements/700/07_plus-128.png" alt="Add to Event" style="width: 50px"/>
</button>

<div>
   <p>Meeting Participants:</p>
   <ol id ="list">

   </ol>
</div>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
var List = document.getElementById('list');

$(function (){
    $("#click-me").click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById('list').style.backgroundColor = "green";
        var entry = document.createElement("li");
        var testText = document.createTextNode("test")
        entry.appendChild(testText);
        List.appendChild(entry);

        return false;

    });
});
```

The background colour is successfully turned green, but no list element can be seen to be added. Why isn't my code working? Thanks

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ay4m05rq/. Have you checked the console for errors? Also note that you can make the code much simpler if you use jquery alone: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ay4m05rq/2/

Comment: The variable `List` must be undefined, Move `var List = document.getElementById('list');` inside `$(function (){ ... });`

Comment: @Satpal even better if it is moved inside click event handler to ensure that list element was created when click event happened

Comment: the thing is, I'm intending later on to use that List on form submit

Comment: @SCraig then initialize it again before doing form submit

Comment: Ok, that worked for me! If you post it as an answer I will click it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put `List` initialization inside click event handler

```
$(function (){
    $("#click-me").click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var List = document.getElementById('list');
        document.getElementById('list').style.backgroundColor = "green";
        var entry = document.createElement("li");
        var testText = document.createTextNode("test")
        entry.appendChild(testText);
        List.appendChild(entry);

        return false;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A jQuery implementation, as you're already using the library:

```
$(function (){
    $("#click-me").click(function (e){
        $('#list').prepend('<li>test</li>').css('background-color', 'green');
        return false;
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nc9guq2r/